# Qt connect lambda

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

Hello I'm trying to connect to my QFrame component using lambda inside QMainWindow construct but I get error

> Qwidget::mousePressEvent, cannot access protected member declared in
>   class 'QWidget'

Here is my code

```
QtTestWindow::QtTestWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{

connect( ui.TopFrame, &QFrame::mousePressEvent, [=]
{

});
ui.setupUi( this );

}
```

Comment: isn't it `connect(&src, &signal(), &dst, &slot())`? where is your destination?

Comment: @user3528438 that's the old syntax, the new one should be preferred

Comment: @user29 What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz No it isn't. In both new and old there is a 4-argument and a 3-argument version. [connect() 1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) and [connect() 3](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3). The 3-argument version is "Equivalent to connect(sender, signal, this, method, type)."

Comment: @SimonWarta in that website there's an example showing the new syntax with a lambda function `QObject::connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::connected, [=] () {
        socket->write("GET " + page + "\r\n");
    });` , I think I'm missing your point

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz The point might be a bit off-topic: I just wanted to point out that user3528438 refers to the new connect syntax as well as the question author.

Answer (score 3):

The `QFrame` class extents `QWidget` and the function is signature is

> void QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) [virtual protected]

In other words **this is not a signal** and you cannot do what you're trying.

For completeness here's the documented signature of a signal

> void QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint & pos) [signal]